# Converting a number to a greyscale color in Java

Tags: java, colors, grayscale

I'm trying to figure out how I can convert a number between 1 and 50 to a greyscale color that could be used here:

```
g.setColor(MyGreyScaleColour);
```

1 would be lightest (white) and 50 would be darkest (black).

e.g.

```
Color intToCol(int colNum)  
{  
code here  
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java uses RGB colors where each component (Red, Green, Blue) ranges from 0-255.  When all components have the same value, you end up with a white-black-gray color.  Combinations closer to 255 would be more white and closer to 0 would be all black.  The function below would return a grayish color, with the amount of white scaled accordingly with the input.

```
Color intToCol(int colNum)
{
  int rgbNum = 255 - (int) ((colNum/50.0)*255.0);
  return new Color (rgbNum,rgbNum,rgbNum);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Something like:

```
float grey = (50 - colNum) / 49f;
return new Color(grey, grey, grey);
```

Comment: Why divide by 49f instead of 50f?

Comment: "how I can convert a number between 1 and 50", I assume inclusive, so: if `n=50` then `grey=(50-50)/49f=0.0`; if `n=1` then `grey=(50-1)/49f=1.0`. You have to divide by 49, not 50.