# Java - Obtain Intensity Value of Particular Pixel Through MouseListener

Tags: java, image, mouselistener

Could someone tell me the class I would need to use in order to obtain the pixel intensity of one specific pixel (a pixel the user clicks) in an image, say, in some JPanel?  This will be a grayscale image if that makes a difference.  Put another way, say the user clicks on some point (x, y) in an image.  How can I get the intensity value of this point (x, y)?

Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if this would break if the user is using a graphics display changing program, such as f.lux ( http://stereopsis.com/flux/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) can do this for color

Use the method

```
getPixelColor(int x, int y)
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780546/converting-a-number-to-a-greyscale-color-in-java) for tips on converting colour to grayscale

Comment: The intensity values will be a scalar between 0 and 1 since it is a grayscale image.  Is there anything similar for such images?

Comment: You could map the colour values to grayscale. The colour you get back using Robot should be related to the gray value. I believe for grarscale the red, green and blue components are equal and will be between 0 and 255.